# Null hypothesis in clinical trial question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, clinical-trials

Consider a clinical trial where we want to study the evolution of the occurence of some event during two time periods, with and without treatment.

We know that, not only a difference close to 0 won't be clinically relevant even if statistically significant, but only a large difference would be clinically relevant.

Please could someone tell me why it would be wrong to consider conducting this kind of test:

$H0: \mu = \mu_0$
$H1: \mu > \mu_0$

where $\mu_0 < \delta$ the clinically significant difference we want to be able to show (target)
and $\mu_0>0$ the limit to consider the difference is uninteresting.

Comment: Since you have a longitudinal study, i.e. collecting information for the same subjects over time, you should include this information in your test (subject) as it is likely to be important.

Comment: What do you mean by it being wrong to test $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$, that you don't want to consider $\mu_0=0$? You indeed run the risk of getting a statistically significant but irrelevant result, but usually the study is powered to reject $H_0$ only if there is a meaningful effect. In the other cases you either overestimated the variance (or sampled a much smaller one), or enrolled far too many subjects (do you know how much this costs?). Testing $H_0: \mu=\Delta$, i.e trying to prove that you're definitely above $\Delta$, is a much higher bar to clear.

Comment: @PBulls : I updated my question, indeed I was considering μ0>0 
We include a number of subjects n high enough to ensure to have a power 1-beta to reject H0 considering a given value of delta but that does not mean that the power to "detect" a difference lower than delta in the same conditions (same n, alpha, and variance) is null. That what the point of my reflexion, I don't know if it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are suggesting a test of non-inferiority with a negative margin, which is a test of *super superiority*. The problem is that "clinical significance" is usually taken to refer to the point estimate of the effect. In other words, the usual scientific discourse is a. prove statistical significance (if anything this just verifies the initial assumptions) and b. report the effect. The scientific community then decides if the effect is or isn't meaningful, which can be a meaningful democracy of dialogue - rather than a rigid prespecified set of laws.

Requiring that your test proves super superiority usually requires an impossibly large sample size to be at all meaningful, and in many respects is no different than creating a more stringent alpha level plus requiring that the point estimate falls above a certain threshold.

This idea can be made rigorous by realizing that, for a fixed sample size, the critical value for a statistical test can be translated into an actual effect size, like an OR or mean difference, which can
be referred to as a significance threshold. Moving this value out to a larger one has a one-to-one correspondence with a lower alpha level for a true null hypothesis test (at a given sample size).

Answer (score 0):

One reason this isn't done is that your proposed approach weights the outcome according to the authors' definition of a clinically important difference (aka, minimally important difference), which may not be representative. It is preferable to determine the difference and the certainty of the difference (ie, p-value). Then, clinicians are free to determine whether the observed difference is clinically important.